# Magento 1.8 order product quantity per 0.1 decimals

Tags: magento-1.8, product, quantity, qty-increment

I’m using Magento 1.8 and I am amazed that I cannot get the system to allow orders of 0.1 quantity. I’m building this store to sell fabrics, per 10 cm’s. So that would be 0.1 meters and I do not want the quantity to represent centimeters to avoid long numbers and customers ordering something in 251 cm’s.

I’ve tried the `qty_increment` field in the Admin > System > Configuration > Inventory but it only accepts full integers.

What I’ve tried so far:

1. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/228756/ <- same bug in Magento 1.5 but produces big fat PHP error in 1.8.
2. think about making all the fabrics a configurable product, but this would mean creating a selection pull down list from 0.1 to 25.0 or so in steps of 0.1 ... very ugly IMHO.

Anybody know how to solve this or is Magento simply not meant for this?

Comment: Why don't you use "cm" or "mm" as a measurement base?

Comment: Hi Tim, I indeed thought of that, but would like that only as a last resort kind of option. In the 'previous shop' in Virtuemart , all customers got used to this way of inputting, and it will make sure customers don't order something like 257 cm's and if you then happen to accidently provide 256 cm, they get to send it back.

Comment: !!! I actually found the solution, you CAN do this in the Backend by going to Product > Manage products > Select a product > Inventory > Enable Inventory > Enable Quantity uses Decimals > Stepsize 0.1 !!! SIDENOTE: Product price MUST be over 1 euro/dollar/any currency, or it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found the solution, you CAN do this in the Backend by going to

> Product > Manage products > Select a product > Inventory > Enable Inventory > Enable Quantity uses Decimals > Stepsize 0.1

---

<sub>***Note:*** Product price MUST be over 1 euro/dollar/any currency, or it won't work.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using "mm" (a smallest possible unit) as a base and then modify input/output so your visitors insert it in any convenient way. Input can be easily customised through JavaScript.

Comment: !!! I actually found the solution, you CAN do this in the Backend by going to Product > Manage products > Select a product > Inventory > Enable Inventory > Enable Quantity uses Decimals > Stepsize 0.1 !!! SIDENOTE: Product price MUST be over 1 euro/dollar/any currency, or it won't work.